# Token authentication for CURL in EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, authentication, curl, response

A client requested that I put together a tool to take a company domain name and somehow come up with the account name. I found an API that I can work with, but I'm not as familiar with doing this in VBA.

Here is the CURL procedure that the site documentation gives to push through a Domain Name, and receive the company name as a response:

```
curl 'https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=segment.com' \
        -u sk_b3b05a8924c4f3df86248b4e38421cfa:
```

After several attempts of receiving the "Please authenticate your request", I've finally gotten to the point where I am receiving an error from the API, I think indicating that I am now correctly calling the API in some way.

Here is my current code. Any idea why I may be receiving this error?

```
{"error":{"type":"api_error","message":"Sorry, something went wrong. We have been notified."}}
```

```
Public Function CallRestAPI2(strUrl1 As String)
    TargetURL = "https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=toplinegroup.com"
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    'HTTPReq.Option(4) = 13056 '
    HTTPReq.Open "GET", TargetURL, False
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    HTTPReq.SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    HTTPReq.Send "-u sk_b3b05a8924c4f3df86248b4e38421cfa"
    Debug.Print HTTPReq.responseText
End Function
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after more reading in the documentation and it was due to not passing the Authentication header the correct way. Here is my code:

```
Public Function CallRestAPI3(strUrl1 As String)
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, myurl As String
    myurl = "https://company.clearbit.com/v2/companies/find?domain=toplinegroup.com"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + "sk_b3b05a8924c4f3df86248b4e38421cfa"
    xmlhttp.Send
    Debug.Print (xmlhttp.responseText)
End Function
```